# GridView returns question marks for hebrew characters

Tags: database, windows, gridview, hebrew

I have a simple gridview which reads data from my SQL server database, and shows it.  The data is partly in Hebrew. But when I use the gidview to read the data - I get question marks instead of Hebrew letters... once i checked my database table it also stored as question marks.

What Should I do ? changing the settings of my SQL server or should I change my SQL command statement

Please need help. 
I am using Vb 2008 Windows Application C# and SQL server 2014

Code

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_C_Request.Text))
        {
            con = new SqlConnection("Server=" + server + ";Database=" + db + ";User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + pass + "");
            SqlCommand Insert_Temp = new SqlCommand("insert into [QAMNI].[dbo].[tbl_Talab_Temp] ([T_ID],[Items_ID],[Car_ID],[Items_Name]) values ('" + txt_T_ID.Text + "','" + txtTempCount.Text + "','" + txt_Car_ID.Text + "','" + txt_C_Request.Text + "')", con);
            con.Open();
            Insert_Temp.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            txt_C_Request.Text = "";
            Get_Count_Insert_Temp();
            Get_Tem_GV();
            txt_C_Request.Focus();
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: can you edit your post with a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a data type nvarchar or nchar in order to store Unicode characters.  Unicode character literals must also be prefixed with N.

So, instead of

```
set address = 'כַּף סוֹפִית'
```

Write to a nvarchar field without the unicode prefix

```
set address = N'כַּף סוֹפִית'
```

Take a look at this: [N prefix before string in Transact-SQL query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/n-prefix-before-string-in-transact-sql-query)

Comment: How can i Change all the collation values ? Give me an example ?

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Solved by N prefix :)